# How to fix unknown error: unhandled inspector error: "Cannot find context with specified id"

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

The following code throws occasionally an `org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException`.

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(by);
element.click();
(new WebDriverWait(driver, 4, 100)).until(ExpectedConditions.stalenessOf(element));
```

The page looks like this (by is a selector for `<a></a>`)

```
<iframe name="name">
  <html id="frame">
    <head>
      ...
    </head>
    <body class="frameA">
      <table class="table">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td id="83">
              <a></a>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </body>
  </html>
</iframe>
```

The message is `unknown error: unhandled inspector error: {"code":-32000,"message":"Cannot find context with specified id"}`. `element` is part of an `iframe` and the click can cause the content of the `iframe` to reload. The exception is thrown while waiting. What does this exception mean and how could I fix it?

Comment: Update your question with the dom structure of your page.

Comment: Switch to the iframe firstly, then find the element and click on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error message...

```
unknown error: unhandled inspector error: {"code":-32000,"message":"Cannot find context with specified id"}
```

...implies that the *WebDriver* instance was unable to locate the desired element.

As you mentioned in your question that the element is part of an `<iframe>` and invoking `click()` can cause the content of the iframe to reload in that case you need to traverse back to the `defaultContent` and again switch back again to the desired `iframe` with *WebDriverWait* and then  induce *WebDriverWait* either for `stalenessOf()` previous element or presence of next *desired element* as follows :

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(by);
element.click();
driver.switchTo().defaultContent(); // or driver.switchTo().parentFrame();
new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.name("xyz")));
// wait for stalenessOf previous element (visibility of next desired element preferred)
new WebDriverWait(driver, 4, 100).until(ExpectedConditions.stalenessOf(element));
// or wait for visibility of next desired element (preferred approach)
new WebDriverWait(driver, 4, 100).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(next_desired_element));
```

Comment: Works, but could `frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt` return because the old `iframe` is still available?

Comment: @user3561614 As the name implies `frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt` involves the _waiter_ and the `switching` both. So won't return.